# php difference between am pm time in hours and minutes

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

How to find the difference between these two times.

I have two times

```
$start_time = '09:30 PM';
$end_time   = '10:45 PM';
```

I want the output

```
1h 15m.
```

How to do with php??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hey friend this will work -

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('09:30 PM');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('10:45 PM');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%hh %im');
```

Output -

```
1h 15m
```

Here `%h` indicates hours and `%i` as minutes. (and h and m after `%h` and `%i` respectively are just strings for display)
For more details of `format()` hour or in minutes [check here](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

Comment: 8:10 PM and 7:40 PM return 0h 30m. Why is that?

Comment: I think thats right. Are you expecting negative sign before that or only want to show 30m?

Comment: @WorldemartDevelopment anything wrong???

Comment: its working fine.....

Comment: @WorldemartDevelopment Great to hear that. Happy Coding :)